# Clip path at center produce unexpected behavior with draggable images

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I have a d3.js application with draggable rectangular images.

On drag, the **x** and **y** attribute of the image is changed.

I am currently making these images **"circular**" by doing

```
image.nodeImage {
  clip-path: circle(60px at center);
}
```

in CSS instead of making a SVG def.

When I drag the images though, the images soon go out of scope. I suspect the "center" in "60 px at center" doesn't dynamically update when I change the x, y of the image.

Are my assumptions correct, and are there ways to get around this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `<basic-shape>` (circle) definition, try a `<geometry-box>` as follows:

```
image.nodeImage {
  border-radius: 50%; /* makes a circle */
  clip-path: border-box; /* uses the border to clip */
}
```